# Django admin how do you add a queryset as a read only linked property field

Tags: django, django-admin

This is what my admin class looks like:

```
@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('associated_risks',)
```

`associated_risks` is a queryset property that I have set in the model like so:

```
@property
def associated_risks(self):
    return Risk.objects.filter(control__project__associated_controls__in=self.associated_controls.all())
```

The isssue is that the admin page it's a read only field shown like this:

[image]

Would it be possible to set it as an m2m field similar to how other m2m fields in the django admin page are set up? (multi select form)

Comment: Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display
You can write a custom method to display the queryset how you'd prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a `__str__` method on your `Risk` model, the queryset will show whatever representation you choose instead of `Risk: AM.Risk1`, so if on your `Risk` model you had a field called `name`, your `__str__` method could be:

```
class Risk(Model):
    name = Charfield()
    ...


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then in the admin, the results would look like `<Queryset [<Risk: name1>, <Risk: name2> ... ]` but django will auto-truncate this if it gets too long. If this is still not what you're looking for, an alternative would be to write another function on the model that just delivers a comma-separated list of the risk names for this sole purpose.

so:

```
@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('associated_risks_list',)
```

and

```
def associated_risks_list(self):
    str = ""
    for risk in self.associated_risks:
        str += f"{risk.name}, "
    return str[:-2] # to trim the last comma and whitespace
```

This would show a read only comma-separated list in the admin

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't get me what I need, I need to be able to see what elements are selected vs the overall. My Risk model already has a string method.